# Number of workers in SPARK standalone cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

How to decide the number of workers on spark standalone cluster mode?
The duration will decreased when I added workers in standalone cluster mode.

For example, for my input data 3.5 G, it would take 3.8 min for WordCount. However, it would take 2.6 min after I added one worker with memory 4 G.

Is it fine to add workers for tuning spark? I am thinking about the risk on that.

My environment setting were as below,

- Memory 128 G, 16 CPU for 9 VM
- Centos
- Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.2.0
- Spark 1.1.0

Input data information

- 3.5 G data file from HDFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune both the executors (number of JVMs and their memory) as well as the number of tasks. if what you're doing can benefit from parallelism you can spin more executors by configuration and increase the number of tasks (by calling partitions/coalesce etc in your code).

When you set the parallelism take into account if you're doing mostly IO or computations etc. generally speaking [Spark recommendation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism) is for 2-3 tasks per CPU core

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I want to tune executors or number of tasks, the information I could get is the log stderr from SPARK Web UI? I have heard that I could modify the number of partitions for tuning. However, I did not know how to start it?

Comment: Look at the documentation for RDD operations https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations you'd see a lot fo them accept number of partitions